# How to read json data from json file in yii to make dependent dropdown

Tags: json, yii

i have two json files state.json and city.json how can i read data from them in yii to make a dependent dropdown select.

state json

```
{
"sates":
[{"regionid":122,"countryid":254,"region":Alabama},
{"regionid":123,"countryid":254,"region":Alaska},
{"regionid":124,"countryid":254,"region":Arizona},
.
.
.
]
}
```

city json file

```
{
"city":
[
{"cityid":6836,"countryid":254,"regionid":122,"city":Abbeville},
{"cityid":19061,"countryid":254,"regionid":122,"city":Abernant},
{"cityid":19116,"countryid":254,"regionid":122,"city":Adamsville},
.
.
.
]
}
```

Comment: I think Alabama should be sting and should have written like "Alabama". Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Why don't you just read the file in with PHP and then use the `json_decode` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('dropdown', "
    $('#dropdown1').change(listval);    
    function listval()
    {

        var regionid=$('#dropdown1').val();//regionid must be the value of option

            var city=".json_encode($cityarr).";
            for(var i=0;i<city_array_count;i++)
            {

            if(city[i]['regionid']==regionid){
                $('#dropdown2').append( $('<option></option>').val(city[i]['cityid']).html(city[i]['city']));


            }



    }
    ");
```

$cityarr is second array in php.
you can replace ".json_encode($cityarr)." with your array.

i hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Yii, but after looking it up, probably the best and most straightforward option is to use the `system.web.helpers.CJSON` class.

What you would do is first read in your JSON file (country.json or city.json) to a string variable. This doesn't need to be a special operation; pretend you're reading in a text file.

Then, use the `CJSON.decode( jsonString)` method, which will return an object containing everything in your JSON file.

As for creating a drop-down select from that, I don't know what your JSON file looks like so I can't help you there.

Comment: i am already having data in json format just need to read it and use

Comment: @BCT did you read the answer properly? use `CJSON.decode(jsonString)`.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Read file into string and get a `responsestring` from your file. You can use file input stream or any for that.

step second: parse it.

```
 try{
    JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(response_str);
    JSONArray jarr=jobj.getJSONArray("sates");

    for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++)
    {
JSONObject jsonobj=jarr.getJSONObject(i);
//here is required data bind it with some UI or do anything.    
long regionid=jsonobj.getLong("regionid");
    long countryid=jsonobj.getLong("countryid");
    String region=jsonobj.getString("region");
    }

    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {

    }
```

Step three: bind values with UI.